# Symlink error 403 with apache

Tags: php, apache, symlink, http-status-code-403

I have a symlink `mysite` in my `/srv/http/` folder pointing to `/home/some-user/somefolder`.
In my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, according to many thread in this site and other forums all around the Internet, I set the following:

```
<Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None    
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/srv/http"
<Directory "/srv/http">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then I changed permission to 777 recursively to my symlink target folder like this:

```
chmod 777 -R /home/some-user/some-folder
```

But if I open my webbrowser and enter `http://localhost/mysite/mypage.php` I get the following error:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.5.14
```

I've read many articles saying to do so, but I still can get it working...

Comment: What is the corresponding line in the Apache access and error logs?

Comment: Ok, found out! I needed also chmod o+x /home/some-user (parent folder to my site folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out! I needed also `chmod o+x /home/some-user` (parent folder to my site folder)

Answer (score 1):

You should chmod o+x the entire path where apache'd go through.
So in your case:

```
sudo chmod o+x /home/

sudo chmod o+x /home/some-user/

sudo chmod o+x /home/some-user/somefolder
```